What is an example of a problem that we strongly suspect lies in NP $\cap$ co-NP but not in BQP?
Motivated by the latest lattice crypto paper (no idea if it's correct), I was wondering if there were any out there that thought perhaps NP $\cap$ co-NP was contained in BQP? Or alternatively, if there is a problem in NP $\cap$ co-NP that we especially strongly suspect is not in BQP?

Related: https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/3888/np-intermediate-problems-with-efficient-quantum-solutions

It is worth mentioning that Bennett, Bernstein, Brassard, and Vazirani proved that relative to a permutation oracle chosen uniformly at random, with probability 1, the class $\text{NP} \cap \text{co-NP}$ cannot be solved on a quantum Turing machine in time $o(2n/3)$.

I literally never think about relativization etc., but doesn't that mean that BQP cannot contain NP $\cap$ co-NP?

Not necessarily. The BBBV theorem works in the "relativized model" or the "query model" or the "oracle model", which has been described as the "perturbative theory for computer scientists". There could be a BQP algorithm that exploits some structure inherent in all of NP$\cap$co-NP and hence avoids BBBV - but we don't know what that structure could be...

Oracle bound is $o(2^{n/3})$.

Correct me if i'm wrong, but Peter Shor probably doesn't like relativization methods... it solves nothing and gives an unreliable answer... it's a non-proof

Regarding the second question as to whether there's a problem splitting NP$\cap$coNP from BQP, assuming (as is standard) that coAM=coNP, then Graph Isomorphism may be such a candidate.
In particular, Graph Isomorphism is in NP, with the certificate being the permutation $\pi$ mapping $G$ to $G'$.  We also know, by Goldwasser and Sipser, that there's an AM protocol for Graph Non-Isomorphism. Thus, Graph Isomorphism is at least in NP$\cap$coAM. But we also think that coAM is equal to coNP (for the same derandomization reason we think P=BPP). Thus it's reasonable, under the derandomization assumption, that Graph Isomorphism is in NP$\cap$coNP.
Nonetheless from all of the work that failed to find a BQP algorithm for the hidden subgroup problem for the symmetric group (and gave reasons why such a failure makes sense, as Christopher Moore explained here), people began to believe that Graph Isomorphism might not have a BQP algorithm. Thus, it's not unreasonable to believe that Graph Isomorphism is not in BQP.
But this last point is debatable. For example, some give credence to Graph Isomorphism maybe even being in P (in which case it would axiomatically be in BQP), as many people did with PRIMES and with Linear Programming.
Either way, Graph Isomorphism is so relatively easy anyways, even classically, that it would make for a bad public-key crypto system. Babai gave a quasi-polynomial time algorithm for this and related problems; the industry also uses versions of NAUTY to easily solve most such problems.
